# Cors policy not allowing upload

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-web-services, cors

Can anyone tell me if i've missed something here. This has been added to the CORS policy in the relavent bucket.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
    <CORSRule
        <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
        <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
        <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
    </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

However, when I  try to do an XHR upload i still get a cross domain error. Banging my head on the wall with this one!

Comment: Does your browser issue a CORS preflight (OPTIONS)?

Comment: Not sure - its chrome on OSX

Comment: Open the Network tab in the developer tools and try uploading.

Comment: It looks like it - a request is made with an OPTIONS method

Answer (score 0):

Can you try specifying allowed headers directly?

```
<AllowedHeader>Content-Type</AllowedHeader>
<AllowedHeader>x-amz-acl</AllowedHeader>
<AllowedHeader>origin</AllowedHeader>
<AllowedHeader>accept</AllowedHeader>
```

Comment: I've tried that - doesn't seem to help. I'm going to investigate the preflight - seems like the most likely candidate!

Comment: Can you update your question with the preflight request and response headers?

Answer (score 0):

Just try to use this. It should work

```
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
    <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
    <AllowedHeader>Content-Type</AllowedHeader>
    <AllowedHeader>x-amz-acl</AllowedHeader>
    <AllowedHeader>origin</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
```